# I made a new site, what should I do to inherit the SEO performance from the old one?

Tags: seo, search

I have very limited knowledge about SEO. The problem I am facing is that after my new website built with wordpress went live, when I search for my website's name, my old website that was built with Wix still appears as the first results, while my new website is not even in the first page.

My new site has its own domain, the old one is hosted by Wix. I didn't pay anything to Wix so the URL is like mysite.wixsite.com.

What is the best practice to promote the new website? Please note that my old site has been around for a long time. Instead of simply shut down the old website and start a new SEO campaign for the new website, is there a way to have my new website inherit the reputation the old one already has with Google? If to do that means I have to pay something to Wix it is OK.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement 301 (permanent) redirects from the old URL to the corresponding new URL in order to preserve SEO. This is the same regardless of whether you are changing a URL on an existing site or moving a site to an entirely different domain.

However...

> the old one is hosted by Wix. I didn't pay anything to Wix so the URL is like mysite.wixsite.com.

This is a problem. Whilst [Wix allows you to implement 301 redirects](https://support.wix.com/en/article/setting-up-301-redirects-from-one-url-to-another), this is only available to paid plans that used a custom domain. As stated in the docs:

> It is not possible to set up a 301 redirect from free Wix URLs

As a desparate workaround, you could perhaps try to implement JavaScript "redirects" from the old pages (if Wix allows you to do this - custom per-page JS - you may need a paid plan?). This will help *users* that follow the old links in the SERPs, however, it won't necessarily help your new site to rank in search engines (much?).

Comment: If JavaScript isn't available (and on Wix I doubt it is) you can fall back to the "poor man's redirect:"  Gutting the content and replacing it with "This site moved.  Click here to see this page on the new site."   That isn't as good for SEO as a redirect, but it is somewhat effective.    The old page usually gets removed from the search results and the new page gets some of the link juice.

Comment: 301 redirect was in my radar. But before I pay for it, I need to ask that after doing it, is it gonna be like connecting a hardwire so Google instantly recognize it and show my new website as the first result? Or is it just like a subtle tweak and it will take time for my new website to clime up the search result ranking?

Comment: @WenShenk "But before I pay for it" - Hold on. As stated above, you also need to have a "custom domain". You cannot redirect from "free Wix URLs" of the form `mysite.wixsite.com` - which is (ideally) what you need to do here (since this is what's indexed in Google).

Comment: @WenShenk Just a thought... if you did register an _additional_ (custom) domain and apply this to your Wix account (having "paid for it"), what does Wix do when you access the old subdomain, ie. `mysite.wixsite.com/<url>`? Does it (301?) "redirect" to the _custom domain_? If so, then you could perhaps implement an additional 301 redirect to your new site from the custom domain?!